# Setting slash commands in discordjs v14, without builders

Tags: discord.js

I've set slash commands using `client.application.commands.set`, and that works fine, but I'm unsure how to add permissions for these commands. I've tried several answers on stackoverflow, but I believe v14 changed how to do this, but the docs haven't been updated and use separate libraries anyways.

Here's my code, simplified.

```js
export default async function(client) {
    let commands = [
        {
            name: `start`,
            description: `start`,
        },
        {
            name: `stop`,
            description: `stop`,
        },
    ]
    await client.application.commands.set(commands, process.env.GUILD);
}
```

My end goal is a script that sets `process.env.GUILD` scoped slash commands that are whitelisted to be used by one role.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out the discord.js.org docs on it [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/ApplicationCommandData) :) It looks like you want to use the `defaultMemberPermissions`, which takes a PermissionResolvable, or integer bit field. You could do something like so:

```
const { PermissionFlagsBits } = require('discord-api-types/v10');
// Then you could access to bit flags like so:

console.log(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageChannels);
```